# facebook Iframe Page tab to generate user access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to implement my application on facebook page tab as mentioned in below docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

Application : https://fantasylite.sportify.io

In this application i am using passport for authentication with Facebook. Since i want this application on Facebook page tab but without login page in it. For that I need to generate user access token without user clicking on login button on Facebook page tab.

I have added a post request to my application for the iframe to send the post request.
`app.post('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});`

Is there a way to generate user access token on Facebook page tab? Using signed_request ? or Facebook graph API ?

Comment: facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/Fantasylite-Page-1310179082340333/app/1191914750831942/

Comment: There is no way to “generate” user access tokens other than sending the user through the login flow. Of course you can trigger that automatically once the user enters your tab – but that is really rather bad UX; providing a link/button so that users can log in to the app when _they_ feel like it, is usually the better alternative.

Comment: @CBroe : Is there any alternative way to get user details ? Name and email without login flow ?

Comment: No, of course not. Details of random users are none of your business. They need to log in to your app and grant it permission(s), before you can get any details about them.

Comment: @CBroe oh ok. Thanks. In my application i have user selections. I need some user identity. 
check this out https://www.facebook.com/Fantasylite-Page-1310179082340333/app/1191914750831942/
I think there should be a way to get few details on page tab or who ever clicks on the team(in app).

Comment: If you want user details, users have to login to your app. (That does of course not mean they have to manually log in every time, if a user that has already logged in to your app returns to it at a later point, they will automatically be “logged in”, and you’ll find their user id in the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request).)

Comment: @CBroe : I am trying to access signed_request from the post request in node server. i have added a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404920/facebook-iframe-page-tab-for-signed-request)